# Remove remote git repository

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-remote

Is it possible to completely delete a remote repository (assuming I have write access). I'm trying to completely clear a repository on BitBucket and push a fresh copy. I know I can delete and recreate the repo on BitBucket itself, but I was wondering if I could just "clear" it on the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand you right, but if you just want to start with a new history you can delete your local repo init a new one, add the remote repositories path to the new local repo and forcepush that one over your old repo with: git push -f origin master

This is not recommendet if you are working with other developers on the same project and if you are not... you should be careful by doing this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. There is no remote "delete repo" command in Git. The closest you can come (which seems appropriate since you want to recreate the repo) is to delete all the remote branches.